# Cannot make modifications to IBOutlet variable

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet

I'm trying to add some items to a NSPopUpButton during runtime, but I cannot make any modifications to it, I can only read values.

(part of) my code:

```
@interface GAH : NSObject {
    // ...
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *popper;
    // ...
}

@end
```

and then my @implementation:

```
@implementation GAH

// ...
-(void)someMethod {
    // in a for loop
    NSString *name = @"a name from the loop";
    [popper addItemWithTitle:name];
    // end for loop

    NSLog(@"items: %d", [popper numberOfItems];
}
```

The last line returns 0 even though the addItemWithTitle gets called multiple times (i made sure the name is set correctly)

The following is also a sign of it's "read-only"

```
[popper setAutoenablesItems:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", [popper isAutoenablesItems] ? @"YES": @"NO");
// Prints "NO"
```

Am I missing something to the IBOutlet declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `NSPopUpButton` even initialized when you are calling it?  A `nil` object will no-op.  At no point in your code are you checking if it is `nil` or not.  I'd put a log statement to see if `popper` is `nil`.  If it is, make sure it is connected in your nib.

Comment: Wow...I'm such a dufus, that was of course the case. Guess I was expecting some sort of error message when trying to assign stuff to null objects (like in java, where I usually belong)